# how to ignore reference version during build process for a project in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I have couple of projects that i call them by reflection , some of this project is used external dll ,when i compile my project every thing works fine, the problem happen when i change the external dll to new version (new assembly version) even though the external dll doesn't changed its code, if i recompile my project it will work fine . the thing is how i can build my project and tell them to ignore the assembly version of the reference.
this is the exception i got in run time
Could not load file or assembly 'TheExternalDLL, Version=9.1.0.61, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=111965d80b18ee08' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT

Comment: Do you try to use IoC instead of pure reflection? You could inject files also.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out, I seem to be having this issue on a weekly basis at the moment with various code-bases. The binding redirect seems to be working well.

Answer (score 0):

Your config file may contain a reference to the previous DLL version number, so you may need to update that. If not, you could try adding a binding redirect to your project config file which includes versions up to the new DLL version number. It might look something like this:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="TheExternalDLL" publicKeyToken="?" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.9.9.9" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

More info: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)